# Transact SQL get 95th item only

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access-2013

Please help me, I need to extract only the 95th item (smallest to largest) per product

for example:

In product #1 i have 11 available record, in order to get it's 95th item i do this calculation
=ROUND(11*(95/100),0)

The 95th item of product#1 should be the 10th item in the record and only the 10th record should be shown
The challenge here is some product contain different number of record in database
What is the best way to do this in transact SQL

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Mark Angelus ! Please let us know which RDBMS you are using : oracle, mysql, sqlite, sql-server, ... ? You should tag your question properly

Comment: i am using MS Access 2013 as my database and I need to extract the data to excel